# How to combined html with c++

Tags: html, c++

I am pretty new to both html and c++ with a´lot of knowledge in c#, I have just writen my first 100% own c++ program a little banking system and need a litte help on how to integrate html.
For example how would i dispaly the funds in html?

IDE Clion.

```
    int press;
    int newFunds;
    cout << "Available funds ";
    cout << funds;
    cout << "$ \n";
    cout << "Press 1 for Withdraw \n";
    cout << "Press 2 for Deposit \n";
    cin >> press;
    if(press == 1) {
        cout << "Amount";
        cin >> withdraw;
        funds -= withdraw;
        newFunds += withdraw;
        if(funds < 0) {
            funds += newFunds;
            cout << "Not enough funds!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Remaining funds ", cout << funds, cout << "$ \n";
        }
    }
    else if(press == 2) {
        cout << "Amount\n";
        cin >> deposit;
        funds += deposit;
        cout << "Funds ";
        cout << funds;
        cout << "$";
    }
    if(press > 2) {
        cout << "Invalid";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I welcome any suggestion!

I have tried to look up som tut but they wherent so good!

Comment: HTML is a hypertext markup language used to layout websites, so it is interpreted and executed by the web browser. Does your C++ application run in a browser?

Comment: @HéctorM. Currenty its just an aplication

Comment: Exactly, a C++ console application, which cannot and is not intended to render HTML

Comment: @HéctorM. Its supposed to run on a offline server and i have it ready but when im coding its not on the server?

Comment: Even though it's on a server, your application needs an HTML interpreter, which is typically a browser. Your application is intended to be executed by the operating system, not the browser

Comment: "*Its supposed to run on a offline server*" - then it is likely intended to *output* HTML, which a client (web browser) that is connected to the server would then render. That is not going to happen in a console, but you will see the output, at least.

Comment: if you want to make a server that means you have a server, written in C++, which creates HTML code when a web browser asks for it. The server never uses cin or cout

Comment: @HéctorM. I use a offline server

Comment: You need to figure out the whole system you want to make, and make that system. In this case, starting with a random part didn't work out for you. You want to make a toilet, and you figured out it needs to go fwsssh when a lever is pulled, so you hooked up a speaker to play a "fwsssh" sound effect when a lever is pulled, and now you are asking how do I add water. I have the sound effect, how do I add the water.

Comment: I highly doubt that the requirements are for you to implement your own GUI web browser. That is  very far from a task that a new person could accomplish.

Comment: Okay i read all of the comments and they all are very good! But i need something easy i checked some of this things but are still a bit lost. I get this with the gui kits sady i cant found any kits for clion, So lets start there what is the best kits in your oppinions for clion?

Answer (score 1):

C++ and HTML can't connect just by creating a localhost web server. To make a "connection" between them, you'll need a C++ API to interact with the server and your C++ program. **FastCGI protocol** is simple and easy for beginners, but maybe not be the best option for more professional projects. Check information about FastCGI++ that's an API for C++. Here is a useful GitHub link that I recommend to start: https://github.com/eddic/fastcgipp.